# how to sum an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I currently have this function

```
function radius(d) {
    return d.values[0].environment["4*"];
        console.log(d);
    }
```

However id liked to be able to average all of the 4* environment values for each document(there are 6 in the example below) and return this as the radius. Im new to JS so no idea how to do this. can you help. here is the structure of the data
[image: structure]

Comment: Use array's `.reduce` function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)

Comment: @curiousdev `reduce` would work here. However the data is nested so it's a little trickier.

Comment: @JosephCho it works under presumption that `environment['4*']` is always present

Comment: And also assuming `environment['4*]` is valid. Yep that's correct

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce function:

```
function radius(d) {
    return d.values.reduce(function(avg, item, index, array) {
        return avg + item.environtment['4*'] /array.length
    },0)
}
```

Comment: The division by the array's length is in the wrong place; it should be outside the reduce: `d.values.reduce((avg, item) => avg + item, 0) / d.values.length;`

Comment: The division is in correct place. Your way was (a+b)/2. My way was a/2 + b/2.

Comment: Ah I see my mistake now: I had run `reduce((avg, item, _, arr) => avg + item / arr.length)` (note no `, 0` at the end), which returns an incorrect value; theory-wise, I did think yours was also correct, but was surprised when I (incorrectly) tested it.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to answer the question accurately without testing the whole data structure. Based on what you've provided this should work:

```
function radius(d) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
    let num = parseInt(d[i].environment['4*']);
    if (!isNaN(num)) sum += num;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

We loop through the array, and if `environment['4*']` is a valid number we sum it up. Functionally it would be:

```
function radius(d) {
    const filtered = d.values.filter((x) => {
      let num = parseInt(x.environment['4*']);
      return !isNaN(num);
    });

    const sum = filtered.reduce((acc, val) => {
      return acc+val;
    },0)

    return sum/filtered.length;
}
```